# Scapy set tcp flow window bigger then 65535

Tags: tcp, scapy, flow-control

When using scapy, how can I set a tcp packet with flow control window bigger than 65535?
I know that writing in scapy:

```
packet1[TCP].window=65535
```

will set the window to 65535; But if there is a need to set windows size bigger then 65535, it should be set in a different way because at the tcp header the window field is just two bytes so it can't be greather than 65535 so it should be done in another way. I know it should be possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort answer is: you cannot set the **field** `TCP.window` to a bigger value than 65535, since it is coded on two bytes:

```
>>> ls(TCP)
[...]
window     : ShortField                          = (8192)
[...]
```

But TCP window **can** be higher than 65535, using the "Window Scale" option. The window value is the value of the `window` field multiplied by 2 raised to the power of the window scale value.

In Scapy:

```
>>> IP()/TCP(window=65535, options=[('WScale', 10)])
```

The value is `65535 * 2 ** 10`, 67107840.